# db_mail SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to queue a message from db_mail and after some validations choose whether to send or delete it?

If you `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`, SQL Server sends it automatically.

Comment: Sounds like something that's more suitable for an application written in the language of your choice.

Comment: Why not create an `SQL Server Agent Job` to validate which ever condition you want to (for example scan a table of pending tasks) every minute or hour and then (depending on the result) actually write the email for you?

Comment: You can use control statements in SQL server and make the decision before calling sp_send_dbmail

Comment: What is the specific problem you are trying to solve?  Can you describe the scenario?  Maybe there's a more sensible approach than the path you're starting on.